# How does the GridBagConstraints work for overlapping objects?

Tags: java, jpanel

This code generates three buttons. Button "One" appears in the "north" and partially covers button "two" located in the east. Button three appears in the southwest. How can I get the same layout with button 1 and 2 overlapping, but without button three?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GridBagButtons {
  private static final Insets insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

  public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JButton button;
    // Row One - Three Buttons
    button = new JButton("One");
    addComponent(frame, button, 0, 0, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
    button = new JButton("Two");
    addComponent(frame, button, 1, 0, 1, 2, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);

   button = new JButton("Three");
   addComponent(frame, button, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);  //Comment out this

    frame.setSize(500, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  private static void addComponent(Container container, Component component, int gridx, int gridy,
      int gridwidth, int gridheight, int anchor, int fill) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy, gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0, 1.0,
     anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
    container.add(component, gbc);
    }
    }
```

Commenting out button three changes the layout. Button one completely covers button two. [modified] Code comes from here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingGridBagConstraints.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the grid size in the GridBagLayout constructor.

i.e.

```
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout(2, 2));
```